# ExtJs FormPanel Buttons not shown

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, formpanel

I'm trying to build a FormPanel in my application, made by a field and two buttons.
The problem is that, while textfield is shown, Buttons are not shown on the view!

This is the Login.js view:

```
Ext.define('appTrial.view.Login',{
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
xtype: 'Login',
alias: 'widget.Login',

config : {
    id : 'LoginId',

    title : 'Welcome',
    resizable : false,
    collapsible : true,
    bodyPadding : '5',
    buttonAlign : 'center',
    border : false,
    trackResetOnLoad : true,

    items : [{
        docked: 'top',
        xtype: 'titlebar',
        title: 'Welcome to My New App!!!'
        },
        {
        xtype: 'container',
        name: 'mainContainer',
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'center',
            pack: 'center'
        },
        //width : '100%',
            items : [{
                layout: {
                    pack: 'center'
                },
                html :'Associa attivita',
                margin: '80 0 0 0'
            },{
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'codAttivita'
                }]
            }],
            buttons :[{
                text : 'Associa',
                itemId : 'btnAssocia',
                formBind : true,
                ui: 'confirm'
            },{
                text : 'Reset',
                itemId : 'btnReset',
                formBind : true,
                ui: 'decline'
            }]
    }]
}
});
```

Does anyone have any idea?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Containers doesn't have the button config. You must define the button config into the formpanel object.

Comment: I tried to put Buttons at the same level of items, inside the config property, but it still does not work